# Python read_text() adding extra strings

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I've created a function that takes in a file with dynamic SQL (and parameters) then returns the end SQL result. It seems to be adding extra strings because my unit test is failing and it shows extra strings.

**My function:**

```
def file_to_sql(filename, kwargs=None):
    """Read file and return SQL statement.

    Parameters
    ----------
    filename: str
        Name of the file to read.
    kwargs : dict
        Keyword arguments to be passed into your SQL statement.
    """

    python_dir = Path('logic/extract/python3')
    python_file_path = python_dir / '{}'.format(filename)
    sql = python_file_path.read_text().format(**kwargs)

return sql
```

**My unit test:**

```
def test_python_file_with_kwargs_to_sql():
    sql = file_to_sql(filename="select_all_from_{table}.py", kwargs={
        'table': 'sandbox.test_table'
        })

    assert sql == "SELECT * FROM sandbox.test_table;"
```

**select_all_from_{table}.py:**

```
"SELECT * FROM {table};"
```

**Unit test failure message:**

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
_____________________ test_python_file_with_kwargs_to_sql _____________________

    def test_python_file_with_kwargs_to_sql():
        sql = file_to_sql(filename="select_all_from_{table}.py", kwargs={
            'table': 'sandbox.test_table'
            })

>       assert sql == "SELECT * FROM sandbox.test_table;"
E       assert '"SELECT * FR....test_table;"' == 'select * from...x.test_table;'
E         - "SELECT * FROM sandbox.test_table;"
E         + SELECT * FROM sandbox.test_table;

tests\unit_tests\transform\test_preprocess.py:19: AssertionError
================ 1 failed, 2 passed, 4 skipped in 1.40 seconds ================
```

Comment: Well for one, your text cases are not matching so `==` will never evaluate to `True`... do a case insensitive comparison like `sql.lower() == 'select * from sandbox.test_table'`.

Comment: Thanks @Idlehands for pointing that out. I've fixed that and confirmed I get the same error.

Comment: See my answer.  You're also missing the double quotes.

Comment: [Path.read_text()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) reads the file contents as a string. There is no need to enclose the contents in quotes.

Comment: @WillKeeling Aha! thank you that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons your unit test is failing:

1. Your `sql` string is in mixed cases ("SELECT" and "FROM" are upper cases) whereas your comparison string is in all lower cases.
2. The text within `select_all_from_{table}.py` are in double quotes but your comparison string doesn't have the double quotes.

Since `read_text()` reads the file content as `str` you don't need the double quotes.  Remove the double quotes from your file and for good practice, do a case insensitive test:

```
sql.lower() == 'select * from sandbox.test_table'.lower()
```

Or just `sql.lower() == 'select * from sandbox.test_table'` will suffice in this particular case.

For unit tests it is best you be vigilant about your input and output and make sure your tests are exact.

Comment: That's the part I don't understand. Why are the double quotes missing during the assert but not missing when I read it from a file?

Comment: Check your file.  Are you sure there's no double quotes in your actual file itself? It looks to me your text file was already containing exactly `"SELECT * FROM {table};"` including the double quotes themselves.

Comment: Yes I didn't realize that read_text() read the file in as a string and that I didn't need the strings inside the file. If you update your answer I would be glad to mark it correct.

Comment: I missed that you had already included the content of the file in your question.  I have updated the answer to address the concerns.  Thanks for being helpful to help us help you (you might be surprised but it's not always the case).